# Programmatically reset VisualStudio shortcuts

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

There are two related questions about [resetting VisualStudio keyboard scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120537/how-can-i-create-a-visual-studio-macro-to-change-the-keyboard-layout) and [importing VisualStudio settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405630/import-export-vs-settings-programmatically). However, this doesn't seem to play nice all together.

I have two settings files containing shortcuts:

```
<!-- IntelliJ.vssettings -->   
<ShortcutsScheme>Visual C# 2005</ShortcutsScheme>
<UserShortcuts>
  <Shortcut Command="ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoNextHighlight" Scope="Global">F12</Shortcut>
</UserShortcuts>

<!-- ReSharper.vssettings -->   
<ShortcutsScheme>Visual C# 2005</ShortcutsScheme>
<UserShortcuts>
  <!-- Implicitly has F12 assigned to Edit.GoToDefinition -->
</UserShortcuts>
```

As you see `ReSharper.vssettings` doesn't really have the `F12` shortcut assigned, since it is the default for VisualStudio. Importing that file, will *not* reapply the `ShortcutsScheme`, which is `Visual Studio C# 2005` in both cases. This in turn results in the fact, that `F12` keeps executing the `GotoNextHighlight` command. Same problem when just using the *import dialog*.

Using `DTE` as follows to reset the keyboard scheme also doesn't work:

```
var property = dte.Properties["Environment", "Keyboard"];
property.Item("SchemeName").Value = "(Default)";
```

Exporting the default settings doesn't work for the same reason. As [shown here](https://gist.github.com/matkoch/120e6de9087df595fcb5289d4e77acc1) no shortcuts are exported.

**Question therefore: How can I reset the VisualStudio keyboard scheme programmatically using DTE?**

What I actually need is the command to trigger the `Reset` button in Options | Environment | Keyboard dialog.

Comment: Also releated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525815/programmatically-change-visual-studio-options

Answer (score 4):

You can remove specific key bindings as per: 
[Visual Studio key bindings configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503447/visual-studio-key-bindings-configuration-file)

Unfortunately I dont have both IntelliJ and ReSharper to test if it works. If it does it'd be nice to do this using DTE however this solution is beyond the scope of DTE and would be trivial using System.IO.File.

**UPDATE:**

> Question: How can I reset the VisualStudio keyboard scheme programmatically using DTE? What I actually need is the command to trigger the Reset button in Options | Environment | Keyboard dialog.

Unfortunately you cannot do it (AFAIK) because resetting the Keyboard Shortcuts is beyond the scope of DTE.

If you setup a VS AddIn Project called "ResetKeyBoard" and put a break point on the `Exec` method you will see DTE doesnt catch any Visual Studio events firing when you're inside the Tools Options window, they simply aren't exposed through the DTE Object model:

```
public void Exec(string commandName, vsCommandExecOption executeOption, ref object varIn, ref object varOut, ref bool handled)
```

This can also be demonstrated by Recording a Macro, the recorded commands only go so deep as to open the Option Dialog (no matter what settings you change inside):

```
Public Module RecordingModule
    Sub TemporaryMacro()
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.Options")
    End Sub
End Module
```

I did learn how to open the Keyboard tab of the Options window directly but since its a Modal Dialog you cant even use SendKeys to press the Reset button:

```
public void Exec(string commandName, vsCommandExecOption executeOption, ref object varIn, ref object varOut, ref bool handled)
        {
            handled = false;
            if(executeOption == vsCommandExecOption.vsCommandExecOptionDoDefault)
            {
                if(commandName == "ResetKeyBoard.Connect.ResetKeyBoard")
                {
                    _applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("Tools.Options", "BAFF6A1A-0CF2-11D1-8C8D-0000F87570EE");
                    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("%e");
                    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

The last DTE option I tried (without luck) is using `Commands.Raise`, again you cant get deeper than opening Tools Options or at least if you can **its undocumented**.

```
public void Exec(string commandName, vsCommandExecOption executeOption, ref object varIn, ref object varOut, ref bool handled)
{
    handled = false;
    if(executeOption == vsCommandExecOption.vsCommandExecOptionDoDefault)
    {
        if(commandName == "ResetKeyBoard.Connect.ResetKeyBoard")
        {
            Commands cmds = _applicationObject.Commands;
            Command cmdobj = cmds.Item("Tools.Options");
            object customIn = null;
            object customOut = null;
            _applicationObject.Commands.Raise(cmdobj.Guid, cmdobj.ID, ref customIn, ref customOut);
```

**Workarounds:**

a) I dont encourage you to replace the Visual C# 2005.vsk file, but if you want to investigate its this file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 1X.0\Common7\IDE\Visual C# 2005.vsk
```

[MSDN Warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.command.bindings.aspx)

> You cannot programmatically change the settings for the default keyboard mapping scheme. To change the settings, save a copy of the default keyboard mapping scheme in the Keyboard node in the Options dialog box. You can then change the settings in that mapping scheme.

I do not recommend or encourage this method, its bad programming and you could destroy someone's keyboard shortcuts!

b) Another way could be by creating your own VSK file and setting it in the currentSettings.vssettings:

```
    </ScopeDefinitions>
     <ShortcutsScheme>Visual C# JT</ShortcutsScheme>
    </KeyboardShortcuts>
```

[image]

Make sure you backup the currentSettings.vssettings file before changing it.

c) This leads back to Chris Dunaway's suggestion where you create a vssettings file (purely containing keyboard shortcuts) and import that in to reset the keyboard shortcuts. I realise the default shortcuts are not saved, however here is some code you can use with DTE to export the commands out, to insert into a new vssettings file to then import in:

```
//note, this is untested code!
public void Exec(string commandName, vsCommandExecOption executeOption, ref object varIn, ref object varOut, ref bool handled)
{
    handled = false;
    if(executeOption == vsCommandExecOption.vsCommandExecOptionDoDefault)
    {
        if(commandName == "ResetKeyBoard.Connect.ResetKeyBoard")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("<UserShortcuts>");
            foreach (Command c in _applicationObject.Commands)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Name))
                {
                    System.Array bindings = default(System.Array);
                    bindings = (System.Array)c.Bindings;
                    for (int i = 0; i <= bindings.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        string scope = string.Empty;
                        string keyShortCut = string.Empty;
                        string[] binding = bindings.GetValue(i).ToString().Split(new string[] {  "::" },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
                        scope = binding[0];
                        keyShortCut = binding[1];
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("<RemoveShortcut Command=\"...\" Scope=\"" + scope + "\">" + keyShortCut + "</RemoveShortcut>");
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("<Shortcut Command=\"" + c.Name + "\" Scope=\"" + scope + "\">" + keyShortCut + "</Shortcut>");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("</UserShortcuts>");
```

Once you've got them out its easy to import them in:

```
_applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", "/import:\"KeyboardOnly-Exported-2016-08-29.vssettings\"");
```

REFs:

[Visual Studio 2005 IDE Tips and Tricks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb245788(v=vs.80).aspx)

[How to reset visual studio settings to my saved settings with just a single shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505805/how-to-reset-visual-studio-settings-to-my-saved-settings-with-just-a-single-shor)

[How does one set Visual Studio 2010 keyboard shortcuts comfortably, especially when using ReSharper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725007/how-does-one-set-visual-studio-2010-keyboard-shortcuts-comfortably-especially-w)

https://superuser.com/questions/914244/is-there-a-quick-way-to-delete-all-shortcuts-in-visual-studio-10

[Remove a keyboard shortcut binding in Visual Studio using Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324550/remove-a-keyboard-shortcut-binding-in-visual-studio-using-macros)

http://vswindowmanager.codeplex.com/

[Get full list of available commands for DTE.ExecuteCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855401/get-full-list-of-available-commands-for-dte-executecommand)

[HOWTO: Execute a command by Guid and Id from a Visual Studio package](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2014/MZ2014018.aspx)

[HOWTO: Execute a command by Guid and Id from a Visual Studio add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008013.aspx)

[HOWTO: Pass parameters programmatically to a command from a Visual Studio add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2014/MZ2014025.aspx)

And finally this one by Jared Par:

https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/blob/master/Src/VsVimShared/Extensions.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Safely reset the keyboard bindings on this Command to the provided values
/// </summary>
public static void SafeSetBindings(this DteCommand command, IEnumerable<string> commandBindings)
{
    try
    {
        var bindings = commandBindings.Cast<object>().ToArray();
        command.Bindings = bindings;

        // There are certain commands in Visual Studio which simply don't want to have their
        // keyboard bindings removed.  The only way to get them to relinquish control is to
        // ask them to remove the bindings twice.  
        //
        // One example of this is SolutionExplorer.OpenFilesFilter.  It has bindings for both
        // "Ctrl-[, O" and "Ctrl-[, Ctrl-O".  Asking it to remove all bindings will remove one
        // but not both (at least until you restart Visual Studio, then both will be gone).  If
        // we ask it to remove bindings twice though then it will behave as expected.  
        if (bindings.Length == 0 && command.GetBindings().Count() != 0)
        {
            command.Bindings = bindings;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Several implementations, Transact SQL in particular, return E_FAIL for this
        // operation.  Simply ignore the failure and continue
    }
```

Comment: errhh Doh, FAIL! Sorry

Comment: Can you try to remove it with the updated info in my answer. Its the same principle as before (removing rather than resetting), just the correct technology this time.

Comment: I will keep this as a back up plan. However, it's not _universal_ enough. I've outlined the IntelliJ/ReSharper schemes as kind of an example. In reality, those vssettings could contain just anything. Settings for presentation, settings for design mode, etc... In those cases I want to keep the shortcuts of course.

Comment: Ok, see my latest update, I did the best I could. Hopefully someone else provides a better answer than the 3rd workaround or JaredPars project.

Answer (score -1):

You can call devenv.exe directly and pass the /ResetSettings switch.  Here is a link to the command line options for Visual Studio:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx

You can execute devenv.exe using the Systems.Diagnostics.Process class to reset the settings:

> Devenv.exe /ResetSettings

You can, optionally, pass a settings file which contains the settings you want to restore:

> Devenv.exe /ResetSettings "C:\My Files\MySettings.vssettings"

In Visual Studio, you can export selected settings by going to Tools > Import and Export Settings... and selecting "Export Selected Environment Settings".  Then, only choose the Keyboard checkbox under the All Settings > Options > Environment subtree.

Comment: @Matthias - Can't you just create a .vssettings file that only contains the keyboard settings and then use that in conjunction with ResetSettings?  See my edit.

Comment: If you export the default settings, it doesn't write anything to that vssettings file. So, no.

Comment: @Matthias -  I'm not sure I understand why this doesn't work.  If you have your keys setup the way you want them in VS, then that is what will be exported into the vssettings file.  My environement (VS2013) is set to defaults for C# and I get an output file.

Comment: Edited my question already, showing that *no* default shortcuts will be exported.

Comment: @Matthias - Can't you just combine the .vssettings files for IntelliJ and ReSharper and import that?

Comment: No, those are two completely different keyboard layouts. How am I supposed to combine them? I really think, resetting using `DTE` is the only option.

Comment: @Matthias - You can't copy the <Shortcut> node that you need into the <UserShortcuts> node of the vssettings file?  I must be misunderstanding.  Create a single .vssettings file with all the shortcuts that you need and then import that.

Comment: @Matthias - Either copy it from another vssettings file, or add the node manually with a text editor of some sort.

Comment: As I said, default shortcuts are *NOT* exported, so I cannot copy them from elsewhere. Adding them manually is kind of *NOT* programmatically, and a lot of stupid work (+ needs work to keep it up-to-date). That's why I'm asking about `DTE` after all.