# The method or operation is not implemented while using DTE.ExecuteCommand("Project.ReloadProject")

Tags: c#

I Wanna reload my project in C# programmability,

after adding a new file:

> "ProcedureCallSQLServer.cs"

to my project:

> "MYCodeGen.csproj"

I am new in this stuff

the steps for achieving this approach are as following:

```
                    // remove compile  line from csproj file.
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"The Path of MYCodeGen.csproj");
            var list = new List<string>(lines);
            list.Remove("    <Compile Include=\"The Path of ProcedureCallSQLServer.cs\" />");
            lines = list.ToArray();

            File.WriteAllLines(@"The Path of MYCodeGen.csproj", lines);

            // Includ .... 
            var p = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(@"The Path of MYCodeGen.csproj");
            p.AddItem("Compile", @"The Path of ProcedureCallSQLServer.cs");
            p.Save();

            //Build ...
            string solution =@"The Path of MYCodeGen.csproj;
            System.Diagnostics.Process build = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe", string.Format("{0} /build", solution));
            build.WaitForExit();
```

Till now, everything is okay, the file is included and builded, but I wanna reload my project for preventing the next message to appear

[image]

after searching , I get the next code:

```
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Project.UnloadProject");
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Project.ReloadProject");
```

But I get the next error:-

> The method or operation is not implemented.

any help ??

Comment: Why my question voted down ?

"This question does not show any research effort " !!

this is not fair !

is my question answerable or not useful ?? !

Comment: I'll fix the -1 for you (it wasn't me), you might like to see this question/answer - what you're asking for maybe beyond DTEs scope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043624/programmatically-reset-visualstudio-shortcuts but Nuget can do it so I think this is *maybe* possible- I'll give it a go later

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson
Thanks bro :) .. I gonna check the mentioned question.